# Model not defined with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, frameworks

I have a problem to make a migration of a model for Django 2.1.
I have created this two class models:

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    post_short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_contents = models.TextField()
    post_publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    post_keyconcept = models.ManyToManyField(KeyConceptModel)
    post_slug = models.SlugField(unique="True")
    post_highlighted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class KeyConceptModel(models.Model):
    concept_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.concept_text
```

When I try to start ***makemigrations***, the console return:

```
NameError: name 'KeyConceptModel' is not defined
```

The error point to the line of ***post_keyconcept***. 
If I comment all of ***KeyConceptModel*** and the line ***post_keyconcept***, the migrations are successfull.

I don't know what is wrong, I'm new into the Django and Python world...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `KeyConceptModel` must be defined first at the top and the class `PostModel` below:

```
class KeyConceptModel(models.Model):
    concept_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.concept_text

class PostModel(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    post_short_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_contents = models.TextField()
    post_publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    post_keyconcept = models.ManyToManyField(KeyConceptModel)
    post_slug = models.SlugField(unique="True")
    post_highlighted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

Here is an interesting link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 3):

You've defined KeyConceptModel *after* you try to use it in PostModel. Your two options to fix this are to either pass "KeyConceptModel" as a string, or to define KeyConceptModel before using it in PostModel.